# Insert Into Table Not Working?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have this code which when I run in my localhost, it is working the way it should. But when I do it in the live database, it is just inserting the first data from the first file. All data types are the same.

```
<?php 

//connect to the database 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("pc2015",$connect); //select the table 

//get the csv file from directory
$dir = "UnzipFiles/";
$currentFile = glob($dir."*.csv");

foreach ( $currentFile as $filename) {
    $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
    $file = basename($filename);

//loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO pcoordinates (gps_id,lat,lng,time,pv,mn,by,ea,bn,cn,hsn,name) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '$file',
                    ".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]).",
                    ".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]).",
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[4])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[5])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[6])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[7])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[9])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[10])."'
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    }
?>
```

This code runs in my localhost and again, its working well. In my live db, I am just changing the connection code. What's missing in my code? Thanks

Comment: assign the query string to a variable and print it. then print the ddl and debug the query ( if its not obvious ) in your sql client

Comment: did you check the connection part? Also check if this directory exist "UnzipFiles/"

Comment: How about using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE instead of PHP https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way,no need to use (+) symbol,take a look at (,)

Sorry ,It is copied from my java code..

```
                + "'" + Txt_G_ID.getText() + "',"
                + "'" + Txt_G_Nam.getText() + "',"
                + "'" + 00 + "',"          //   ^........... 
                + "'" + 00 + "',"         
                + "'" + 00 + "',"
                + "'" + 00 + "',"            
                +"'"  + 00 +"',"
```

Comment: explain it later,,its time to go to my office